# "in his spare time" or "in my spare time"

Tags: pronouns

I have a short description of myself but I'm not sure whether I should use "my spare time" or "his spare time"

> Hey! I'm an embedded software engineer who enjoys making discord bots in his spare time.

Coming from German this is how I would say it, and how it sounds correct for me. But someone mentioned to me that it should be in "my" spare time instead. What version would be correct?

Comment: Either would work, but "my" is probably a bit more idiomatic.

Comment: I agree with @Hot Licks that both would work. But you should also stay consistent with your usage of similar expressions in the rest of the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are idiomatic in English: you can either use “my” or your third person singular pronoun.

The reason for this is because the pronoun comes after “who”. Otherwise you would have to use “my” (for example, “I am his own boss” is ungrammatical).

Here’s an [example with *his*](http://inothernews.tumblr.com/post/35682478112/fighting-mad):

> I think I am known as a person who expresses his opinion freely about things

Here’s an [example with *my*](http://www.mcleodandmore.com/anger-v-depression-two-sides-of-the-same-coin/):

> I am also a person who buries my emotions

(Both these examples were found with [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) using [collocation searches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ1wO.jpg).)